# Android Studio: Set ProgressBar background color with RemoteView

Tags: android, android-widget, android-remoteview

I have this progressbar view:

```html
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="20"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_shape"
        android:progressTint="#03ff46" // this is the value I'm trying to set via RemoteView
        android:progressBackgroundTint="#a8a8a8" // also this one
    />
```

I'm trying to set the background color & fill color with RemoteView (I'm using it for a widget)

```html
views.setInt(R.id.progressBar, "setProgressTintList", clockData.getDarkColor());
```

My widget can't load, so this must be the wrong way to do this.

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` as that tag is for questions/issues with the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio

Comment: What do you mean by "my widget won't load"? Please explain in more detail exactly what the problem is. Do you get exceptions, errors? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: by "my widget won't load" I mean that when updating my widget and going to the home screen, I see a white box with the text "Widget could not be loaded" meaning there's an issue with my code.

Comment: If you remove the calls to `views.setInt()` does your widget show? Did you check the logcat for errors?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `setProgressBackgroundTintList()` and `setProgressTintList()` on your remote `View`s. Both these methods take a `ColorStateList` as a parameter. So you need to call `views.setColorStateList()` to do this. See
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews?hl=en#setColorStateList(int,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList)

---

`ColorStateList` is used to set a list of colors depending on the state of a UI element (pressed, enabled, selected, etc.). If you only want to set the color, regardless of its state, you can simply create a `ColorStateList` that contains a single color. Here's an example of creating a `ColorStateList` containing just a single color programatically and using that to set the color in `RemoteViews`:

```
ColorStateList csl = ColorStateList.valueOf(clockData.getDarkColor());
views.setColorStateList(R.id.progressBar, "setProgressTintList", csl);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this allows me to set colors programatically. Would it be possible for you to show me an example?